# map.getCenter.lng() extends beyond -180 when dragging continuously. How can I stop that?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

heres my code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(e) {
    console.log(map.getCenter().lng();      
});
```

when dragging the map horizontally repeatedly it will produce a pattern such as:
0, -60, -120, -180, -240, -300

But i was hoping for:
0, -60, -120, -180, 120, 60

Is this a bug in gmaps or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some would say a bug, while others would say it was a feature. To be fair it would seem like the "correct" behaviour, but it just doesn't give you any usable results.

I believe the most common way of getting past this "feature" is to make sure your value is never below -180 og above 180. An easy way to accomplish this is to always make the call:

```
map.getCenter().lng() % 180;
```

This will always give you the modulus 180 which is the remainder when you have subtracted by 180 until the value is in the correct range.

Comment: Thanks Kasper. I would think gmaps should supply both options, one too see how many times over the user has scrolled and then the other with a number to work with. With you suggestion I came up with

Comment: `var lngCenter = map.getCenter().lng();
  var rem = lngCenter % 180;
  if (Math.abs(parseInt(lngCenter/180)) % 2 !== 0)
  {
   if (rem < 0)
    rem += 180;
   else
    rem -= 180;
  }
  lngCenter = rem;`    Is there anything more efficient I can do?

Answer (score 3):

just updating this to add an answer from here:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3247

as in the link above , you can create a new LatLng object which will correctly wrap the longitude.

```
var center = map.getCenter();

var wrapped = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat(), center.lng());
```

I found that using my own math dividing my 180, I would still hit some contrived situations where a pixel or two drag around the prime meridian would cause incorrect measurements to be calculated - maybe my maths wasn't bang on, but in any case - the above seems to me to be a better fix.