# Google map get center does not return valid longitude

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am working with google map.i am facing issue
When I have dragged the map to reach to the -180 longitude, after dragging so far to the left side. If I click on "Get center" button it is giving wrong longitude.

```
var map;
    function initialize()
    {
    var mapOpt = {
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
      zoom:3,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
    map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOpt);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',initialize);
```

Here is fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/3Ld249ap/2/

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What do you mean by "a wrong latitude"? What do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: I get negative values such as -384.12 but that is a valid value in term of longitude. If you want to keep values in the [-360,+360] range you can compute `boundLng = lng % 360;`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [map.getCenter.lng() extends beyond -180 when dragging continuously. How can I stop that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680371/map-getcenter-lng-extends-beyond-180-when-dragging-continuously-how-can-i-st)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it is working for me

```
var mapCenter = map.getCenter();

var location = new google.maps.LatLng(mapCenter .lat(), mapCenter .lng());
```